# Iptables LOG rule inside a network namespace

Tags: networking, iptables, docker, containers

I'm trying to setup iptables rules for a docker container. I'm using [nsenter](https://github.com/jpetazzo/nsenter) to execute the iptables command inside of the container's network namespace:

```
# log access to port 8080
PID=$(docker inspect --format "{{.State.Pid}}" $ID)
/home/ubuntu/nsenter -n -t $PID iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j LOG
```

This approach works perfectly except for `LOG` rules. Those don't seem to log anywhere. Note that the same rule applied to the host system works and logs to `/var/log/kern.log`.

Where can I find the output of those log rules? Is this a known issue/limitation of network namespaces?

Comment: Update: I tried `NFLOG` instead but it still won't work

Comment: I did a test using a docker container based on centos 7 and it's works, the host is a centos, the same test with ubuntu Ubuntu 15.04 host and ubuntu 12.04.5 container doesn't works, anyway you need to be sure, the syslog is running in your host.

Comment: I'm using Debian wheezy as a host and Ubuntu 14.04 in a container. There it doesn't work. I'm wondering what is different there.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @gucki I did not find a solution to get it working inside of the namespace. I moved the logging rules outside of the container.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Donald mentioned, iptables LOG rules inside containers are suppressed by default.

In kernels <=4.10, this behavior could not be adjusted without patching the kernel.  As agrrd mentioned, a work-around is to run ulogd in each container and use iptables NFLOG (or ULOG) rules instead of LOG rules.

However, as of kernel 4.11, running `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_log_all_netns` on the host (outside of the container) will cause iptables LOG rules inside all containers to log to the host.  [(See this Kernel Commit.)](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit?id=2851940ffee313e0ff12540a8e11a8c54dea9c65)

Answer (score 3):

The output of iptables LOG targets from inside a network namespace is suppressed by design to prevent containers from DOSing their host by overrunning its log buffers.

[commit introducing the change](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=69b34fb996b2eee3970548cf6eb516d3ecb5eeed)

[relevant source code line in the current kernel](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_log_ipv4.c#L321)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to log iptables rules for docker containers by installing ulogd and replacing "-j LOG" with "-j ULOG". Matched packets are logged to /var/log/ulog directory

Comment: Did you install ulogd on the host (gives no output from the rule) oder inside the container (which does not start)?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen an example (not kernel related) of using `-v /dev/log:/dev/log`. I wonder if you need to do something similar..

Also, I see that you are using nsenter rather than `docker exec`: what version of docker are you running?

Comment: It's also not working when not using docker at all, but netns manually from the command line.

Comment: You'd nee /proc/kmsg or /dev/kmsg and docker effectively prevents you from mounting that in the container.